# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot create property 'reply' on number '1000'

Tags: javascript, typeerror, discord.js

I am currently writing a discord bot using discord.js and am stuck on this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot create property 'reply' on number '1000'
```

The error appears every time the 'Robbery' is successful.
This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
let coins = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./coins.json', 'utf8'));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let userDiff = args[0];
  let userChance = 0.333 * userDiff;
  var userEarned = 0

  let numAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * userDiff) + 1;

  if(userDiff > 10){
    messange.channel.send('Please enter a number between 1-10')
  } else if(userDiff <= 10 && userDiff >= 9){
    var userEarned = 1000
  } else if(userDiff < 9 && userDiff >= 8){
    var userEarned = 900
  } else if(userDiff < 8 && userDiff >= 7){
    var userEarned = 800
  } else if(userDiff < 7 && userDiff >= 6){
    var userEarned = 700
  } else if(userDiff < 6 && userDiff >= 5){
    var userEarned = 600
  } else if(userDiff < 5 && userDiff >= 4){
    var userEarned = 500
  } else if(userDiff < 4 && userDiff >= 3){
    var userEarned = 400
  } else if(userDiff < 3 && userDiff >= 2){
    var userEarned = 300
  } else if(userDiff < 2 && userDiff >= 1){
    var userEarned = 200
  }

  console.log('numAmt: ', numAmt);
  console.log('userChance: ', userChance);

  if(numAmt <= userChance){
    message.channel.send('Robbery was Succesful you earned ', userEarned)
    coins[message.author.id]['coins'] += userEarned
    fs.writeFile("./coins.json", JSON.stringify(coins), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
    });
  }

  if(numAmt >= userChance){
    message.channel.send('Robbery was Unsuccesful you have been arested, You can pay to bail out or wait 5 mins')
  }

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'bankrobbery'
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant put in actual code instead of image

Answer (score 1):

In your code you wrote this:

```
message.channel.send('Robbery was successful, you earned ', userEarned);
```

That means that you're passing a string as the message and then `userEarned` as [`MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions), as stated by the docs of [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).
What I think you want to do is merging the two strings: you can do that by using the `+` operator.

```
message.channel.send('Robbery was successful, you earned ' + userEarned);
```

Alternatively, you can use another string syntax:

```
message.channel.send(`Robbery was successful, you earned ${userEarned}`);
```